# R: divide a given Box into X amount of new boxes with given diagonal

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf, geosphere

I have a Bbox of Germany with coordinates (lon,lat):

```
g_bbox<-c(xmin=5.98865807458, ymin=47.3024876979, xmax=15.0169958839, ymax=54.983104153)
```

I would like to divide the bbox in **(x)** amount of bboxes with a diagonal of **50 km** each.

The length of diagonal can vary a little **(+/-10km)**.

The Resulting BBoxes should not overlap.

The amount of BBoxes **(x)** should be the maximum number of BBoxes that fit into the **g_bbox**

The result I would like to have is in best case a data frame with **xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax** columns.

How would I go about it?

Comment: I assume the bounding box is latitude/longitude given that you mention Germany? Is "x" given (the number of boxes)? If not it should be straightforward to divide the latitude up into roughly 50km stripes, and then make many narrow boxes across each stripe

Comment: Hi Miff, yes its lon,lat format. I adjusted the questoin a little to make it more clearer. Interresting suggestion, thank you. How would i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following solution.

Load packages

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.0, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1
```

Load data

```r
g_bbox <- st_bbox(c(xmin = 5.98865807458, ymin = 47.3024876979, xmax = 15.0169958839, ymax = 54.983104153), crs = 4326)
```

Convert bbox to polygon with projected coords

```r
g_poly <- st_as_sfc(g_bbox) %>%
  st_transform(32632)
```

Plot

```r
mapview::mapview(g_poly)
```

[image]

Create the grid

```r
g_grid <- st_make_grid(g_poly, cellsize = 50000 / sqrt(2))
```

Check one diagonal

```r
sqrt(
  (st_bbox(g_grid[[1]])[3] - st_bbox(g_grid[[1]])[1]) ^ 2 # x axis
  +
  (st_bbox(g_grid[[1]])[4] - st_bbox(g_grid[[1]])[2]) ^ 2 # y axis
)
#>  xmax 
#> 50000
```

Plot

```r
mapview::mapview(g_grid)
```

[image]

Estimate all bboxes

```r
head(do.call("rbind", lapply(g_grid %>% st_transform(4326), st_bbox)))
#>          xmin     ymin     xmax     ymax
#> [1,] 5.970445 47.30249 6.455849 47.63163
#> [2,] 6.440454 47.31382 6.923301 47.64117
#> [3,] 6.910729 47.32325 7.390967 47.64877
#> [4,] 7.381223 47.33077 7.858798 47.65445
#> [5,] 7.851885 47.33638 8.326746 47.65819
#> [6,] 8.322667 47.34009 8.794764 47.66001
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>